# How to make a floating box in the center of the screen with responsive layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get into responsive design/layout with Bootstrap and CSS, but I am kind of confused of how could a change a box to be in the center of the screen.

I have a login pane that in Google Chrome has size 277x256 (that size could fit many smartphone screens). So I made a CSS like that:

```
.login .pane {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -128px -138.5px; /* half of the size in Google Chrome */
    background: #f0f0fd;
    background: rgba(240,240,253,0.90);
    padding: 22px 32px;
}
```

You can see the complete code in: http://jsfiddle.net/H5Qrh/1/

=== UPDATE ===

I made a cleaner code and tried using Absolute Centering instead of Negative Margins:

```
.center-pane {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 277px;
    height: 320px;
}
```

My updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5Qrh/3/

Now the footer is above the box.. that shouldn't occour.

Comment: [Absolute Centering](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt)

Comment: I updated it.. it is getting closer.

Comment: I think that's the best you can do without JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `absolute` but I'd change that to `fixed` (this will work on both).

I set your height and widths, but you can change them, and because you want it responsive, you can change them with a few media queries. For example mobile you might want width to be 90% or 100%.

```
.login .pane {
  position: fixed; /* could be absolute */
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/H5Qrh/2/)